# How to exclude an entity set from EF6 dbContext?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

I have this context.cs file:

```
public DbSet<Type1> Entity01 { get; set; }
public DbSet<Type2> Entity02 { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new Entity01Map());
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new Entity02Map());
}
```

But I would like to exclude from dbContext the Entity02, so I comment the two lines of code where entity02 is used:

```
public DbSet<Type1> Entity01 { get; set; }
//public DbSet<Type2> Entity02 { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new Entity01Map());
    //modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new Entity02Map());
}
```

But when I use the dbContext I get an error that say that Entity02 has not key definied. But I don't know how can EF that I have an Entity02 type because I comment the lines where is referenced.

So I would like to know how to exclude some entities from my dbContext because in some cases I don't need that entities and I would like to have a dbContext in which exclude them.

Thanks.

EDIT: add the code of my two entities

```
public partial class Ficheros
        {
            public Guid Idfichero { get; set; }
            public long Iddocumento { get; set; }
            public byte[] Fichero { get; set; }

            public virtual Documentos IddocumentoNavigation { get; set; }
        }

public partial class Documentos
    {
        public Documentos()
        {
            ElementosDocumentos = new HashSet<ElementosDocumentos>();
        }

        public long Iddocumento { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public long? IdtipoDocumento { get; set; }
        public string Codigo { get; set; }
        public decimal? Espacio { get; set; }
        public string Unidades { get; set; }
        public long? Bytes { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ElementosDocumentos> ElementosDocumentos { get; set; }
        public virtual Ficheros Ficheros { get; set; }
        public virtual DocumentosTipos IdtipoDocumentoNavigation { get; set; }
    }
```

I would like to exlcude Ficheros. In this case, Ficheros has a FK to Documentos, so yes, Ficheros is a child of Documentos.

Comment: EF will only know about that class if it's part of the entity hierarchy, does `Entity02` exist as a child property of `Entity01`?

Comment: I have added the code of the entities.

Comment: Well the entities are linked to each other, you can't exclude one and have the other.

Comment: Where is setted the link between both? Because If I don't have references to Ficheros in the context.cs file, where is stored this relationship between the two entities? I would like to exlcude Ficheros in the way that EF doesn't know that exists this entity.

Comment: In the entity! `Ficheros` has `public virtual Documentos IddocumentoNavigation` and `Documentos` has `public virtual Ficheros Ficheros`...

Comment: Thanks, I see know. Then in my mapping file with fluent API i can use the ignore to ignore the propierty Ficheros in my Documentos entity and ignore IDDocumento in my Ficheros entity, si I don't need to set up the relationship between them.